# is there a more convenient version of iproute (ip a d)?

Tags: iproute

Using the `iproute2` command  `ip address delete` (or shortened `ip a d`) allows to delete a protocol address (see [`man ip address`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip))

Problem `ip a d` is rather inconvenient in its usage, requiring more parameters than indeed needed for having sufficiently specified its task. Really? example:

```
user@box$> ip a s 

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:ee:9a:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.192.0.174/24 brd 10.192.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 415283sec preferred_lft 415283sec

user@box$> ip a d 10.192.0.174

Not enough information: "dev" argument is required.

user@box$> ip  a d 10.192.0.174 dev wlo1

Warning: Executing wildcard deletion to stay compatible with old scripts.
     Explicitly specify the prefix length (172.22.52.254/32) to avoid this warning.
     This special behaviour is likely to disappear in further releases,
     fix your scripts!
```

Case in point
since in most cases the assigned ip address is only assigned to a single network device, I really wonder how to make `iproute2` just get its act together and delete the ip address already, instead of making me copy pointlessly the netmask and the network device.

Even thought I at present struggle to see a use-case where multiple network device would be assigned the very same IP, or cases in which a Ip address is assigned multiple times with diverging subnet masks (which incidently must have been the cases that `iproute2` is not willing to ignore), I am certain that even those cases could be helped with `iproute2` on a **if it actually happens basis** (meaning, in case of ambiguity only).

Has anybody found a way to make `ip a d` less pointlessly worksome?

BTW/Bonus: is there a way to have `ip a a [ipadress]` default to a less pointless netmask than `/32` / `255.255.255.255` (or is there a reason for this choice?) ?

Comment: It's working as documented anyway: `ip address help` states that for `del` the `dev` parameter is mandatory. For some other sub-commands it's optional

Comment: @A.B and it could also be mostly optional for `ip a d` too. Something which my example provided showed and was hoping somehow this question would find an answer to. Sadly even if I quick&dirty write a little shell function to supplement this behavior (i.e. to append the only device associated with the given ip), it would only ever be readily available where this shell function is first copied over to.  So on off-the-rack `iproute` only system I will be anoyed to always have to provide the device, albeit it being completely detectable anyway.

Comment: keep cool I gave you an answer

Comment: you are right. thank you for the answer. I guess it stressed me to run into the mostly pointless "oh you forgot the device, hahah" error messeage today. The flush seems a nice find, thankyou for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: I completely agree with @Yurko's answer. Yet here's a answer which should still solve your problem.

If you want to delete one address without considering the interface, you shouldn't use `ip address del` but `ip address flush`, as the help page hints:

> ```
>       ip address {save|flush} [ dev IFNAME ] [ scope SCOPE-ID ]
>                             [ to PREFIX ] [ FLAG-LIST ] [ label LABEL ] [up]
> ```

This subcommand is used to do bulk removal of addresses. You can limit its scope in various ways. One way is the `to PREFIX`.

So for your case this will work:

```
ip address flush to 10.192.0.174
```

It will even remove this address multiple times in complex setups where it appears on multiple interfaces.

Stating a netmask there would select the whole range to search for deletion candidates, so it's probably best left without netmask. This is a different behaviour than `del`, because the role of the command is different. For example `ip address flush to 192.0.2.100/31` would select any prefix starting with 192.0.2.100 or 192.0.2.101, whatever their own netmask (which could be /32 /24 or whatever), for deletion. `delete` would probably answer there's no such address.

Answer (score 2):

iproute2: yes, there are reasons, including multiple interfaces, virtual interfaces, complex routing, bond interfaces, etc., finally legacy and the same behavior on all *nix systems.

You need to have it configured once and forget about it, so no reasons to invent a wheel again.

If you have to do it multiple times, iproute2 provides with full set of tools to easily have it scripted in few minutes and forget about it.

---

Netmask 255.255.255.255 is default for a reason, it puts each device into its own subnet, forcing them to communicate through router on a way reaching any other devices... so if you do not enter local network netmask -> you have no local network. But again, you can have it easily scripted or even simply changed by creating an alias.

Comment: One cannot really argue that the _Linux-specific_ `ip` command is as it is because it has to have the same behaviour on other operating systems.